Deploying huggingface model
I have been trying to use a Llava endpoint in sagemaker when following this tutorial (https://github.com/aws-samples/multimodal-rag-on-slide-decks/blob/main/Blog1-TitanEmbeddings-LVM/notebooks/0_deploy_llava.ipynb).
I haven't used the Cloudformation, I am just interested in deploying the model itself.
The endpoint is deployed however, when I try to invoke it i get the following error:
ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message 
{
  "code": 400,
  "type": "InternalServerException",
  "message": "GET was unable to find an engine to execute this computation"
}

Not quite sure what to do and what the exact issue is.
I have deployed the model successfully, confirmed that the Sagemaker role has alld the Endpoint policies attached.

Can you provide an example how you invoke the endpoint? This model expects data in a specific format. If you follow the further examples in the linked repository, it shows also examples how run inference against the model

I have followed the example shown and even tested a few other formats. When I was testing other formats, specific errors were raised indicating that.

It seems this is related to CUDA as documented here
The cuda versions from running nvidia-smi and nvcc --version need to match
You could also check the endpoint's logs
